# does %x[] catch all output?

Tags: ruby

If I run this code:

```
svn_output = %x[svn update /Users/radek/Sites/db2.rft -r 11105 --force ]
puts
puts " output is  =#{svn_output}="
```

I get this result

```
svn: Working copy '/Users/radek/Sites/db2.rft' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)

 output is  ==
```

but I want the error message from svn inside the variable `svn_output`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
svn_output = %x[svn update /Users/radek/Sites/db2.rft -r 11105 --force 2>&1]
puts
puts " output is  =#{svn_output}="
```

Comment: Or use [open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) if you need to differentiate between `stdout` and `stderr`.